# What can I do with mushrooms?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I've managed to grow a **flat mushroom** via the stumps outside my house, and I'm expecting more.

What can I do with these mushrooms other than sell them?

Answer (score 1):

[During November](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/faqs/65246) there will be a [**mushroom picking event.**](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Mushrooming_Season) During this event (whenever it may be), [picked mushrooms can be pieces of the **mushroom furniture set**](http://www.animalcrossingcommunity.com/Topic/5755151/1/).

Other than that, the Perfect Mushroom will cause the player to increase in size for a short period of time.  As this effect is purely cosmetic,  I'd recommend just selling them (except during the event of course).

Comment: That link is not very helpful. For example, it doesn't mention the mushroom furniture at all - how is the mushroom picking season related to the furniture set? It also doesn't say anything about the mushrooms I find _now_. Can I save the mushrooms I find now until then for an advantage, like in the Bug Off?

Comment: @JoeWreschnig You won't be able to stockpile them because the picked mushroom _is_ the item during the event. I've updated my answer with a few more specifics, but I have found a date discrepancy.  Personally, I'd put money on New Leaf following City Folk's schedule and having the event occur in November.

Comment: IGN is the only place I've seen referencing the October dates for New Leaf, while I've seen multiple referencing November.  Unless someone else can confirm otherwise, I'm going to say it's in November.

Comment: Previous AC games had the mushroom event in November.

Comment: @KatieK According to the wiki, the only game it was in Novermber in was City Folk.  Wild World did not have a Mushroom Picking Event, but it did have the Acorn Festival in November.